# Azure:build pipeline:Error The type or namespace name 'XXXX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, mobile-automation, azure-devops, cicd

I am trying to **build task** in Azure pipeline. Observed error :

> **The type or namespace name 'XXXX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Please let me know if anyone face/fix this issue.